Invoke-SqlCmd vs SqlCmd
I have to tried to find the source code for Invoke-SqlCmd, but to no luck.  My question is: Does Invoke-SqlCmd use sqlcmd.exe behind the scenes?
Additionally, are there any SQL Server commands available for PowerShell Core on Linux?

"My question is: Does Invoke-SqlCmd use sqlcmd.exe behind the scenes?" What's provoking the question?

re sqlcmd.exe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59177628/cant-find-sqlcmd-exe-sql-server-2017

To install the SqlServer module on PowerShell Core in Linux simply install it.
Install-Module -Name SqlServer

More information: Manage SQL Server on Linux with PowerShell Core
Also: cmdlets currently available in PowerShell Core
As the cmdlets currently available in PowerShell Core also include Invoke-Sqlcmd and that they need to work cross-platform, this indicates that it does not use sqlcmd.exe behind the scenes. Additionally, the documentation for Invoke-Sql state:

Runs a script containing statements supported by the SQL Server SQLCMD utility.

So it "fakes" the syntax for backwards compatibility and to upgrade existing scripts. But there are a few specific commands that are not supported, which also is an indicator that it is not running sqlcmd.exe in the background.

After the SqlServer module is installed, use Get-Command -Module SqlServer to see what commands are available.
